# Bad request when calling a WCF webservice

Tags: android, wcf, post

I have an android application. I want to send a request to a WCF web service.

The services is:

```
[OperationContract]
Message submitData(Stream streamdata);



[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "submitData")]

public Message submitData(Stream streamdata)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);
        string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse(JsonSyncManager.submitVotes(jsonString), "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

I tried the service on Fiddler and it was working correctly.

However from my app I try the following

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("voters", "test");


String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8733/Service/submitData";

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

StringEntity s = new StringEntity(j.toString(), "UTF-8");

s.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.setEntity(s);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

But i always get a Bad request error. It does not reach the service (will not enter the breakpoint).

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks

Comment: Try enabling tracing on the server side - the traces should tell you why the request is being considered bad.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem: 400 Bad Request.
Try to change Content-Type:

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

It fixed problem for me.